# EJB remote injection can return object by reference

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, wildfly-8

we add to wildfly
on section
subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:2.0"
in-vm-remote-interface-invocation pass-by-value="false"

top level deployment with a META-INF/jboss-ejb-client.xml

ejb-receivers local-receiver-pass-by-value="false"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have 2 Facade A and B , A Inject B by remote injection , the object return from B to A , return by value and not by reference , i need to return object by reference .

Comment: the application server used is wildfly 8.0

Comment: @JohnMick did you get any solution or workaround for this? if, Yes, can you post it here?